# How to make the computation faster?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, sequence, square

Here is short code which computes sum of all square numbers(not actually sum of squares) till n,where n can be upto 10 pow 20.

```
    long long res=0;
    long long sm=0;

    for (long long i = 1; res <=n; i=i+2)
    {
        res = (res+i);
        sm  = sm+(res*(n/res));

    }
```

How do we make the above code work faster? Here, the computation of sm is taking time for very large n like  10 pow 20.

Is there any way that the computation of sm can be made faster?

Here res computes all the square numbers like 1,4,9,16,25....

Lets say n=10, then the squares are 1,4,9 and then by the above code the sm is (1)(10/4)+(4)(10/4)+(9)(10/9)=27.

1*10+4*2+9*1=27.

**Here the division is integer division.**

edit1:

i need to compute `sm` mentioned in above code.

here `sm` is summation ( **i<sup>2</sup> * floor(n/(i<sup>2</sup>))** ) where i=1 to sqrt(n)

Comment: If you are trying to answer some online judge test or code quiz, please add a link to the original problem statement. I, for one, am sure not to have understood what you are supposed to do.

Comment: http://codeforces.com/contest/616/problem/E ,http://www.spoj.com/problems/SUMPRO/ are the two similar problems . I just wanted to know how to solve  the above problem as well,just for my curiosity i am running on my system. But its very slow.

Comment: Please post the link to the original question. The description of your question is unclear. SQRT result is double. You want ceil or floor of that. Same for n/(i^2). Integer deivision. Next: Competetive programming question can mostly not been solved by a brute force approach. You need to come up with mathematics. Last: The code quality of competetive programming is ultra bad. You should **never** take such examples for learning C++. E.G. no serious C++ developer would name the variable for a sum "sm". That's rediculous.

Comment: I need the integer division for n/(i^2) and sqrt result is floor. And it is not a competetive programming problem. I changed the problem from the above mentioned links.And the example i mentioned is (1)*(10/1)+(4)*(10/4)+(9)*(10/9)=27. And about c++ i am trying to learn cpp and become a gud developer thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

we can find the sum of all square number till n using the formaula :

> n * (n + 1) * (2*n + 1) / 6

```
long summation(long n) 
{ 
    return (n * (n + 1) *  
        (2 * n + 1)) / 6; 
}
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't answer my question? How does that compute sm value mentioned in the above code . Lets take for example n=10, squares below that are 1,4,9. Now the sm will be 10+8+9=27.But by your answer it is 385 i guess for n=10.

Comment: @prolific what is your problem statement? What do you want to compute?

Comment: I want to compute  summation( (i^2)*( n / ( i^2 ) ) ). Sorry for the poor editing i dont know how to use math symbols here.

Comment: did u get the problem?

Comment: @prolific I understand what sm compute but what is the actual problem statement you are trying to solve. If you are trying to solve the homework pls specify the entire problem statement or if there is any link for the problem  you are trying to solve.

Comment: http://codeforces.com/contest/616/problem/E ,http://www.spoj.com/problems/SUMPRO/ are the two similar problems . I just wanted to know how to solve  the above problem as well,just for my curiosity i am running on my system. But its very slow.

Comment: @prolific use <sup> raised stuff </sup> tags to write in superscript. I edited that in your post.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way that the computation of sm can be made faster?

If you notice the pattern plus apply some mathematics, yes.

The next perfect square after your very first perfect square (1 in all cases except for `n==0`) will be the square of `ceil(sqrt(first number))`.

In other words, the square root of say the nth number, in correspondence to your first number will be given by `pow(ceil(sqrt(L)), n)`.

Now, notice the pattern between squares: 0 1 4 9 16 25... 
Difference between 0 and 1 is 1 
Difference between 1 and 4 is 3 
Difference between 4 and 9 is 5 
Difference between 9 and 16 is 7 
Difference between 16 and 25 is 9, and so on.

This makes it clear that the difference between two perfect squares is always an odd number.

Proceeding with this knowledge, you'll need to know what must be added to get the next number, the answer to which is `(sqrt(square) * 2) + 1)`.

i.e., `current_square + (sqrt(current_square)*2+1) = next_square`.

For instance and to prove this equation, consider the perfect square 25. Applying this logic, the next perfect square will be 25 + (sqrt(25) * 2 + 1) = 36, which is correct. Here 11 is added to 25, which is an odd number.

Similarly if you follow this trend, you'll observe all these numbers are odd, with a difference of +2. For finding the next square of 2, you'll need to add (sqrt(2<sup>2</sup>)+1) = 5 to it (4+5=9); for finding the next square (i.e. for 3) you'll need to add (sqrt(3<sup>2</sup>+1) = 7 to it (9+7=16). The difference is always +2.

Moreover, summing the odd number or applying addition is computationally less expensive than performing multiplication or finding square roots of every number, so your complexity should be fine.

---

Following that, do this:

- Collect the first square. (which ideally should be 1, but if `n>0` condition is not mentioned,  apply the condition `if(n!=0)` to my logic)
- Assign the next term's difference as `first_square*2+1`. You'll need to add the first square though, as this is not the next square, but the difference between next square and current square. Add the term in a loop like I did below.
- Run a loop upto your required number. Collect your required sum given by `(square*floor(n/square)` in a variable within the loop.
- Follow the approach I mentioned above, i.e. add the current square to the `next` term (difference between current and next square) and increment next square by 2.

A working example for the above logic:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#define ll long long 
int main() 
{ 
    ll int n; 
    std::cin>>n;

   // Start from 1: (add case for 0 if input is not >0)
   // you can also start from any other square or define a range.
    ll int first = 1; 

   // Square it:
    ll int first_square = first * first; 

   // Find next square:
    ll int next = (first_square * 2) + 1; 

   // Initialize variable to collect your required sum:
    ll int sum = 0;
    ll int square = first_square;

    while ((square >= 0 && square <= n)) 
    {  
        sum += (square *floor(n/square));

        // Add the perfect square: 
        square += next; 

        // Next odd number to be added:
        next += 2;      
    }     
    std::cout<<sum;  
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I think it won't give the correct result. You can see the example i mentioned . For n=10 , the squre numbers are 1,4,9 then the sum would be 27 but your sum gives 29

Comment: @prolific Check now. Took quite some time to write that down.

Comment: Is the time complexity  of above code better than the one in the post ? If so, what is the time  complexity ?

Comment: It should be less since it uses additions, and check squares directly. Test this code and let me know.

Comment: Whats the difference  in time complexity... I guess this is greater than o(sqrt(n)). In my code it is O(sqrt(n))+time for computing the sum.  O(sqrt(n)) for finding the squared numbers.  What about the above code... What is the time complexity  of total code.

Comment: Any how there is some multiplication  in the above code while computing  the sum which is actually  causing  the trouble i guess.  When i ran the program on my system computing squre numbers is better where as computing the sum is difficult  . But in your code theres no change in computation of sum.

Comment: @prolific It definitely isn't more. It runs up till n but only for the squares, it is similar to yours. (eg: loop runs 3 times for 10, 10 for 100, which is 0(sqrt(n)). Change the data type to long long.

Comment: I will test the code.  But what i am saying is about the computation  of sum not the square numbers.  Computation of sum is taking  time.

Comment: n = 10^10, n=10^15, n=10^20

Comment: @prolific I tested it on jdoodle, it runs in a second for 10^10. For 10^15 and 10^20 its fast enough but overflow would occur, you'll need to take modulus of sum.

Comment: @prolific I doubt its a case of time complexity. O(sqrt(n)) is as fast as it could get. What you are missing here is the overflow for cases 10^15 and 10^20.

Comment: Tested no change it's taking time on my system.For n= 10^16 its taking 3 seconds